# Why does "Your Phone" application automatically close on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, your-phone

I keep "Your Phone" and "EasyMail for Gmail" open on my Windows 10 laptop.  I periodically find that the applications are not running.  So, I start them, use them and later I find that they closed.  I wondered if I was closing them by mistake.  I left them running but did not use the laptop.  I came back and both closed.  The laptop did not go to sleep or hibernate.

There is no indication of a crash.  Only these two applications close.  I have 7 other applications with windows on the taskbar all the time.  These applications do not automatically stop running.

The 2 problematic applications were installed via Windows Store.  The other applications are not.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with them being UWP apps and being suspended and terminated under low memory situations: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle

Comment: @Mokubai Is there any way to disable this "feature"?